# Windows SBS 2000 Server to Windows 2008 (optionally Core) Migration

Tags: windows-server-2008, active-directory, migration, windows-sbs

Is there any known procedure of migrating services from SBS 2000

- Active Directory
- DNS
- disabling Exchange 2000
- DFS

What to avoid? What to apply? Any scenarios?

I thought to make vhd backup of current physical win 2000 sbs instance, upgarade to win 2003, next to 2008...

I would be grateful for any opinions

Answer (score 0):

As far as Active Directory goes I'd set up the Win 2008 machine as Secondary Domain Controller, then upgrade the domain, then switch PDC role over to the new machine after synch has been done.

I have no experience with the rest (DNS should be quite simple to configure though, so "migrating" might be too big of a word for it, if not, you're probably doing something wrong :)).